# Laravel 5 - Returned json is a simple string

Tags: php, json, laravel

Scenario: REST api where a client requests data from server via GET method

I am returning an array from HomeController (Server side: Laravel 5)

```
return ['Status' => 'Success', 'SearchResponse' => $apiresponse, 'AuthToken' => $property];
```

The above response is generated from a URL `http://example.com/flightSearch`

On the client side (Laravel 4)

```
        $input=Input::all();
        $url = 'http://example.com/flightSearch';
        $data = array(
             'client_id' => 'XXX',
             'api_secret' => 'YYY',
             'method'=>'SearchFlight',
             'adult'=>$input['adult'],
             'children'=>$input['children'],
             'infant'=>$input['infant'],
             'departCity'=>$input['departCity'],
             'arrivalCity'=>$input['arrivalCity'],
             'departDate'=>$input['departDate'],
             'returnDate'=>$input['returnDate'],
             'journeyType'=>$input['journeyType']
             );

        $params = http_build_query($data);
        $result = file_get_contents($url.'?'.$params);

        $response = json_decode($result);
        return $response->Status //Works
        return $response->AuthToken //Works
        return $response->SearchResponse //Throws following Error
```

Error:

```
The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString()
```

Solution:

The variable `$apiresponse` was an object returned from a remote server. Adding the variable to an object solved the problem

```
return ['Status' => 'Success', 'SearchResponse' => array($apiresponse), 'AuthToken' => $property];
```

Comment: `var_dump($response)` and check what is the type of your variable?

Comment: how is the data stored in `$response`? and what are you doing to get/fetch the data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Update

Since you have a JSON string you can simply use `json_decode()`:

```
$response = json_decode($result);
return $response->Status;
```

---

> The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString()

This is just because you're returning the `$response->SearchResponse` from your controller action. Using it like `$response->SearchResponse->SomeProperty` will just work fine. No need for `array($apiresponse)` If you want to see all the contents of that variable use `var_dump()`:

```
var_dump($response->SearchResponse);
```

---

Assuming you created the `$response` with Laravels help this should be an instance of `Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse`.

You can get the data (already decoded) with `getData()`:

```
$data = $response->getData();
echo $data->Name
```

Comment: I tried but no luck `Call to a member function getData() on a non-object`

Comment: Can you please update your question with the full code on how you get `$response`

Comment: And `$response = json_decode($result); return $response->Status;` didn't work?

Comment: Cool! This work but for only Status and AuthToken. But `$response->SearchResponse` throws error. I am updating my question

Answer (score 0):

```
$test1 = array('name'=>'gggg');
print_r($test1); //answer: Array ([name]=>gggg)
$test2 = json_encode($test1);
print_r($test2); //answer: {"name":"gggg"}
$test3 = json_decode($test2);
echo $test3->name; //answer:  gggg
```